# Fetch child entities when finding by a normal field in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data `JpaRepository` to find List of entities matching a particular field. Consider the following code snippet:

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "master")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Master implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long Id;

@NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Details Details;
```

**Spring Data Custom JpaRepository:**

```
public interface MasterRepository extends JpaRepository<Master,Long> {

    List<Master> findMasterByUserId(String userId);

}
```

When i am using `findBookingMasterByUserId` repository method to find all records with specific user id, I am getting the List of `Master` entity but I am not getting the `Details` entity that has `id` as foreign key in it.

However, I get all the dependent entities when I use out of the box `findAll` method of `JpaRepository` but with custom `findMasterByUserId` repository method, child entities are not being fetched eagerly.

Any type of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Tried with `@Query`?

Comment: @Rossi I don't want to write the custom query but want to use JpaRepository itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity name is "Master" not "booking_master".

Change your method to:

```
List<Master> findByUserId(String userId);
```

Refer to below spring docs for more information on query creation mechanism for JPA.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Alternatively,

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Master m WHERE m.userId = :userId")
List<Master> findByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

The query generation from the method name is a query generation strategy where the invoked query is derived from the name of the query method.

We can create query methods that use this strategy by following these rules:

- The name of our query method must start with one of the following
  prefixes: find…By, read…By, query…By, count…By, and get…By.
- If we want to limit the number of returned query results, we can add
  the First or the Top keyword before the first By word. If we want to
  get more than one result, we have to append the optional numeric
  value to the First and the Top keywords. For example, findTopBy,
  findTop1By, findFirstBy, and findFirst1By all return the first entity
  that matches with the specified search criteria.
- If we want to select unique results, we have to add the Distinct
  keyword before the first By word. For example, findTitleDistinctBy or
  findDistinctTitleBy means that we want to select all unique titles
  that are found from the database.
- We must add the search criteria of our query method after the first
  By word. We can specify the search criteria by combining property
  expressions with the supported keywords.
- If our query method specifies x search conditions, we must add x
  method parameters to it. In other words, the number of method
  parameters must be equal than the number of search conditions. Also,
  the method parameters must be given in the same order than the search
  conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Tanmay. I mistakenly wrote findBookingMasterByUserId instead of findMasterByUserId in the question.

Comment: Actually I don't want to write query instead in want to use spring's own JpaRepository to perform the task.

Comment: You only write findByUserId not findMasterByUserId. Return type itself specifies List of Master to be returned. Try with my first answer that uses Spring's own method. List<Master> findByUserId(String userId);

Comment: How does that answer the question? I understood the question to be about eager / lazy loading?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@EntityGraph` in your repo to eagerly get associated data:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"details"})
List<Master> findBookingMasterByUserId(String userId);
```

P.S. Don't forget to change 'Details' field to `details`;

Comment: I will surely try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: @gschambial , if the answer helped you don't forget to accept/upvote it.